# How to run single script .py just as you would in command line, Python. See simple project

Tags: python

So I have a simple matplotlib plot produced in the command line (Windows) with this from the book, Python for Data Analysis.

```
C:\Users\Wes>ipython --pylab
Python 2.7.3 |EPD_free 7.3-1 (32-bit)|
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
IPython 0.12.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
? -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help -> Python's own help system.
object? -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
Welcome to pylab, a matplotlib-based Python environment [backend: WXAgg].
For more information, type 'help(pylab)'.
In [1]: import pandas
In [2]: plot(arange(10))
```

My code looks more like so...

[image]

It then offers me up a nice plot like so...

[image]

This was a task in itself because in the tutorial, the EPDFree does not exist anymore and the upgrade has it's conflicts, so fresh install of everything and in 64. I will be happy to append this installation process to the bottom if others ran into the same issue.

My goal now, is how do I get this into a .py file. I really want this to fire from my IDE (pycharm) while testing and later celery or some sort of cron-like action. So to simplify my question, how do you prepare a script file to simulate what I learn from command line tutorials. There has to be a better explanation than what I am finding. For example, I can not do this...

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plot

plot(arange(10))
```

or

```
import pylab as plb

plb.plot(range(10))
```

Forgive me, I am a week into python, but I just need to understand this part before moving forward. I am stuck, help a brotha please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.plot(np.arange(10))
plt.show()
```

You cannot work interactively from PyCharm. The big advantage of IPython is that you can manipulate the existing figure. The IPython notebook is a very good tool for such kind of work:

```
ipython notebook
```

You may need to install some needed packages.

Comment: This got it to work running in PyCharm. Not sure what you mean by working interactively or the advantages of running in shell for automated projects I have in mind. I am coming from web applications in PHP, so maybe just need to pick up on things more.

Comment: Of course you can work from PyCharm editing your source. You need to restart from the command line every time you want to see the digram though. IPython just updates it after each change. Very nice for exploration.

Comment: I get it now, I was able to append new data in ipython... thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a plot window to open, just create a `figure`, plot your data and call the `plt.show()` function in the end:

```
import pylab
pylab.figure()
pylab.plot(range(10), range(10))
pylab.show()
```

`ipython`'s `pylab` mode does that extra work for you.

Comment: Not exactly a compared example, but +1 for getting the exact same results. Is that figure() doing something that is not already built from show(), like loading it sooner. Because I can get it to work without.

Comment: @Shane I don't think so, probably not. A figure is created automatically in that case, I just didn't know it worked like that :)

Comment: `pylab` does a lot of magic. As long as you work with just one plot this is fine. As soon as it gets more complicated you likely want to use the more verbose object-oriented approach. Making instance of figures and the like.